# Will delete user for Oracle 10g database deleted the data corrsopds to the user?

Tags: oracle10g

I am new to the Administration part of the Oracle server,Just want to know will deleting a user means data related to that user will also get deleted?
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review cascade option for drop user command 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9008.htm#SQLRF01811

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon what you mean by "related". Every user in the database has a corresponding schema, with tables, indexes and so on. If you drop a user, their schema and all the data in it goes too. If the user has put data into other tables, that data does not go anywhere.